# can't pass object to html with nunjucks

Tags: node.js, template-engine, nunjucks

I want to use Nunjucks to pass data from a mongoDB server to my html file to render on load.

**App.js**

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    database.retrieveComments(req, function(err,result) {
        console.log(result);
        res.render('index.html', result);
    });
});
```

where my database connection file has this:

**connection.js**

```
retrieveComments: function(req, callback) {
    db.collection('comments').find().toArray(function(err,result) {
        if (result.length > 0) {
            return callback(null, result);
        };
    });             
},
```

Lastly, in my HTML file I have this part:

**index.html**

```
<div id="p" class="task" commentId = "1">
    1st comment {{ result }}
</div>
```

I can see result when I console.log it out, but I don't seem to render it in the html file when I browse to the localserver.
If I just pass a string, I can see it, but not when I pass the result object.

I'm wondering if there's some asynchronous node black magic working here, or whether I'm missing some key Nunjucks element.

Comment: Use `res.render('index.html', {result: result});` or `1st comment {{ result.smth-prop }}`

Comment: neither of these works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    database.retrieveComments(req,function(err, result) {
        if (err)
            return next(err); // Always check error
        console.log('DB result: ', result); // Verify that result is not empty
        res.render('index.html', {result: result});
    });
});
```

---

```
retrieveComments : function (req, callback) {
    db.collection('comments').find().toArray(function(err, result) {
        // callback must be called always
        if (err)
            return callback(err);

        if (result.length == 0) 
            return callback(new Error('Result is empty!')); 

        callback(null, result);
    });
},
```

---

```
<div id="p" class="task" commentId = "1">
1st comment {{ result }}
{{ result[0].name }} {# result is Array, right? #}
</div>
```